# Jquery .load loads page slowly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using this code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {
$('.container').load('dashboard.php');
}, 10000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div. it is in milliseconds.
});
// ]]></script>

<div class="container"><h3>Loading Dashboard...</h3></div>
```

to reload a webpage every X Seconds but on the first load it seems to take a while to load/display

if i type the page name in the address bar (domain.com/dashboard.php) it loads instantly

is there any way to make it load quicker?

Comment: What do you mean it is taking a while, here it is set to load every 10 sec... maybe from the address bar you are loading cached content ..

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` waits for the defined number of milliseconds before it calls the function for the first time. So either set the content of `.container` on the server side (using php) instead of 'Loading Dashboard...' or load the content on page load:

```
function reloadContainer() {
    $('.container').load('dashboard.php');
}
setInterval(reloadContainer, 10000);
```